# How to multiple underline characters in strings

Tags: text, strings, underline

I need to show examples of border, cover and other regularities on a string and I would like to show that by underlining the characters of a string accordingly. Also I would like to have a larger font for example strings similar to the attached picture. What would be the best way to achieve something like this?

I have tried `\uline` to underline but didn't achieve the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Do you need to have lines above and below the text, especially over and below the same  character?

Comment: @DrecksHippy no that is not needed. Only below will suffice.

Comment: Then try `\underline{<text>}` to underline and for the font size `{\Large <text>}`. Here is a list of available size changing commands [https://latex-tutorial.com/changing-font-size/](https://latex-tutorial.com/changing-font-size/)

Comment: @DrecksHippy ok, but i need the multiple \underlinde below to highlight the properties that ovelap each other can this be done using underline?

Comment: As long as you want to underline the whole section that was underlined - yes, like in your third to last line.
Otherwise you could use braces and work with [oubraces](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/ftp/pub/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/oubraces/oubraces.pdf)

Comment: @DrecksHippy I also want to underline overlapping parts like for example the second to last example in the picture attached in the question. Such case can not be done with `\underline` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the answer of egreg I just changed one command to get the overlines below the first level underlines - so here it is

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\doubleunderline}{m}
{
    \raisebox{-2pt}{\underline{#1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mmm}
{% #1 = string
    % #2 = doubleunderlines
    % #3 = underlines
    \texttt
    {
        \large \vens_foo:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
    }
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vens_foo:nnn
{
    \vens_foo_lines:Nn \doubleunderline  { #2 }
    \vens_foo_lines:Nn \underline { #3 }
    #1
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vens_foo_lines:Nn
{
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\tl_map_tokens:nn { #2 } { \__vens_foo_line:Nn #1 }}
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vens_foo_line:Nn
{
    \int_compare:nTF { #2 = 0 }
    { \hspace{0.5em} }
    { #1{\hspace{0.5em}\vphantom{Ay}} }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \foo{abacaccababa}{100000000001}{111000000111}
    
    \medskip
    
    \foo{abacaccababa}{111011100111}{001110011100}
    
\end{document}
```

This results in

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can specify over and underlines as binary strings:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\textoverline}{m}
 {
  \ensuremath{\overline{\mbox{#1}}}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mmm}
 {% #1 = string
  % #2 = overlines
  % #3 = underlines
  \texttt
   {
    \large \vens_foo:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vens_foo:nnn
 {
  \vens_foo_lines:Nn \textoverline  { #2 }
  \vens_foo_lines:Nn \underline { #3 }
  #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vens_foo_lines:Nn
 {
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\tl_map_tokens:nn { #2 } { \__vens_foo_line:Nn #1 }}
 }
 
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vens_foo_line:Nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #2 = 0 }
   { \hspace{0.5em} }
   { #1{\hspace{0.5em}\vphantom{Ay}} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\foo{abacaccababa}{100000000001}{111000000111}

\medskip

\foo{abacaccababa}{111011100111}{001110011100}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution! It looks like the right path! However I am not very familiar with defining custom commands in LaTex - would this also work for double underlines that are overlapping like the second to last example in my attached image? If not, how could I change the solution to make it work for my case. Thank you!